# coldfusion 9 files encoded with cfencode.exe not working on coldfusion 10

Tags: coldfusion

i have some coldfusion files that were encoded with cfencode.exe on coldfusion 9. when we try to run the same files on a coldfusion 10 server we get the following error;

w/ufffd, on line 97, column 169, is not a valid identifer name.

The CFML compiler was processing:

The body of a CFQUERY tag beginning on line 90, column 58.

apart from from the different coldfusion versions, the original coldfusion 9 files were encoded on a windows system, and the coldfusion 10 server is a linux - i don't know if that makes a difference.

if i upload a non encoded version of the same file, it works fine.

also, for some reason, its ignoring the application error handling ( the application file isn't encoded )

anyone have any ideas whats going on?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot run encoded ColdFusion applications on a different major version from the one used to do the encoding. If you want to run that application on ColdFusion 10, you will need to re-encode it from the source code using ColdFusion 10.

Comment: thanks carl, downloading coldfusion 10 at the moment